# Bing Maps autoadjusting infobox for its content

Tags: bing-maps

I am adding bing maps to one of our sites. I am able to show pushpins and infoboxes.
The problem I am facing now is the infobox content go out of the white box.
Is there a way to have autoadjusting infoboxes for bing maps or its CSS?

Fixed using Jquery:

```
function displayInfobox(e) {

    pinInfobox.setOptions({description: e.target.Description, visible:true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,4)});
    pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
    map.setView({center:e.target.getLocation(),zoom:4});
    adjustHeightInfobox();
}

function adjustHeightInfobox() {
    var newHeight = jQuery(".infobox-info").height();
    pinInfobox.setOptions({height:newHeight+15});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the default infobox within the AJAX control, you will be able to use the infoboxOption class where you can easily specify the width and height of the infobox.

See the MSDN for all options available on this specific class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx

If you want to adapt the infobox to your own needs (i.e. dynamic size), you can use your own HTML content and customize is with your own CSS, see: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#Infobox14

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed it using jquery by getting the height of infobox-info div and applying that+15 to infobox as height :)